# How to scan USB drive with clamav on Linux

Tags: linux, antivirus, usb-drive

Is there a way to scan the entire drive including auto-run and all partitions, including the master boot record (MBR)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that cannot be done with ClamAV. See the comments on [this site](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2996129&group_id=105508&atid=641464). Definitions are missing for such viruses as well I don't see the patch applied to the clamav I have installed.

Answer (score 5):

In Linux anything is a *file*. That includes your devices' MBR. 
All you need to do is simply preform a scan on the associated 
device driver file.

To find this do the following in your terminal:

`mount | grep -e (media|mnt)`

This will search your mounted devices for anything
in `/media` or `/mnt`. Typical distros use `/media/`, you should
know your location just by browsing to the root of the device.

Next you should see from the output of mount something like the
following:

`/dev/sdb1 on /media/sdb1 type ext3 (rw)`

The device `/dev/sdb1` is the second device(b), first partition(1) 
after the MBR/GUID table. Thus your device *file* you want to scan 
is `/dev/sdb` and you would scan with

`sudo clamscan -i /dev/sdb`

Make sure you do regular backups with `tar(1)` and/or `dd(1)` as well

Comment: **Note:** If you use `pam_usb` you can even have this automatically scan the device on insertion.

Comment: didnt work, "Data scanned: 0.00 MB"? it is mounted btw. I tried that at /dev/sdb1 too and the same result..

Answer (score 3):

Go to where it is mounted (presumably /media/) and run clamscan like you normally would (-r). (Or you wouldn't have to go where it is if you want to use the -i flag)

Comment: But there could be a virus in the mbr, and your method will not check for that.

Comment: If you did get a virus in your mbr you can just rebuild it and that will get rid of at least a few I know of that will infect it.

Comment: I don't know if there is a virus in the mbr, but I want to find out. Not just rebuild. Thanks, though.

Comment: You can see if the total system memory is seemingly missing bytes to check if your mbr has been corrupted - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/82923